# Should Separate ViewController.Swift be Created for each Scene / Screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new to iOS development but have used MVC frameworks on other platforms.  In ready through the getting started documents about view controllers, it seems that there are several approaches in it's use. 
I'm building an app that will have numerous pages / scenes.  In using the storyboard, I'm creating a scene for each screen e.g. sign up, log in, home, and feeds to name a few.  My question is should a separate view controller be created for each screen e.g. signupcontroller.swift, logincontroler.swift etc.?  I started with the single screen project in XCode and have not been able to locate the automated way to create a new view controller for each scene.  Is this indeed a manual effort, or is there a better starter projet type for a robust app such as this one?
Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally have a separate view controller class for each "scene," although it is often the case that several scenes will share a view controller with different data associated with them. Once you make the scene in the storyboard, you create a new UIViewController class and then associate it with a view controller in the storyboard...

Add a new Cocoa Touch class to the project
[image: Add a new Cocoa Touch class to the project]

Name the view controller
[image: Name the view controller]

Associate the view controller in the storyboard with the new class you created.
[image: Associate the view controller in the storyboard with the new class you created.]